# What is the equivalent of connecting to google cloud storage(gcs) like in aws s3 using s3fs?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, fsspec

I want to access google cloud storage as in the code below.

```
# amazon s3 connection
import s3fs as fs 

with fs.open("s3://mybucket/image1.jpg") as f:
    image = Image.open(f).convert("RGB")


# Is there an equivalent code like this GCP side?
with cloudstorage.open("gs://my_bucket/image1.jpg") as f:
     image = Image.open(f).convert("RGB")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for [`gcsfs`](https://github.com/fsspec/gcsfs). Both s3fs and gcsfs are part of the [`fsspec`](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) project and have very similar APIs.

```py
import gcsfs

fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem()

with fs.open("gs://my_bucket/image1.jpg") as f:
     image = Image.open(f).convert("RGB")
```

Note that both of these can be accessed from the fsspec interface, as long as you have the underlying drivers installed, e.g.:

```py
import fsspec

with fsspec.open('s3://my_s3_bucket/image1.jpg') as f:
    image1 = Image.open(f).convert("RGB")

with fsspec.open('gs://my_gs_bucket/image1.jpg') as f:
    image2 = Image.open(f).convert("RGB")

# fsspec handles local paths too!
with fsspec.open('/Users/myname/Downloads/image1.jpg') as f:
    image3 = Image.open(f).convert("RGB")
```

fsspec is the file system handler underlying pandas and other libraries which parse cloud URLs. The reason the following "just works" is because fsspec is providing the cloud URI handling:

```py
pd.read_csv("s3://path/to/my/aws.csv")
pd.read_csv("gs://path/to/my/google.csv")
pd.read_csv("my/local.csv")
```

Comment: You were too fast for me to answer :)

Comment: haha :) couldn't pass up an opportunity to rave about gcsfs!!

Comment: It's very useful.Thank you @MichaelDelgado.I didn't know it was that easy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cloud storage client libraries. They have an example [in their docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#downloading-an-object).

If there's no client library for your language then you have to use [the api](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get) though client libraries are available for python.